# multiply two vectors, component by component

Tags: matrix, vector, arithmetic

Would like to take two vectors and multiply components at the same index.For example {a1, a2, a3} x {b1, b2, b3} to produce  {a1 b1, a2 b2, a3 b3}.
The following works, but are there some alternatives?

```
aMat = DiagonalMatrix[{a1, a2, a3}];
bMat = DiagonalMatrix[{b1, b2, b3}];
Diagonal @ Dot[aMat, bMat] 
result: {a1 b1, a2 b2, a3 b3}
```

Comment: `{a1,a2,a3}*{b1,b2,b3}` will give the required answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to do anything fancy. This is just how ordinary list multiplication works:

```
{a1, a2, a3} {b1, b2, b3}
```

yields

```
{a1 b1, a2 b2, a3 b3}
```

Comment: thanks!  didn't even think to try that.